# Why \ifnum\c@mpfootnote does not work inside tabular?

Tags: tables, footnotes, minipage

Why `\ifnum\c@mpfootnote` does not work inside tabular? Should not I get no footnote-rule? I am just puzzled!

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\long\def\@mpfootnotetext#1{%
 \ifnum\c@mpfootnote=\@ne\let\footnoterule\relax\fi
  \global\setbox\@mpfootins\vbox{%
    \unvbox\@mpfootins
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
         {\csname p@mpfootnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}
\makeatother
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{lp{.8\textwidth}}
1&2\footnote{1}\\
1&2\footnote{2}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

A more simplified example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\long\def\@mpfootnotetext#1{%
 \ifnum\c@mpfootnote=\@ne\let\footnoterule\relax\fi
  \global\setbox\@mpfootins\vbox{%
    \unvbox\@mpfootins
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
         {\csname p@mpfootnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}
\makeatother
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\hbox{\footnote{1}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the full intention of the code is but each table cell is a local group so your setting of `\footnoterule` is lost before it is used.

```
\global\let\footnoterule\relax
```

makes the rule go.

Comment: Possibly the best ever answer to MWE length ratio!